# For what $t$ is $M_t=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x^2-y^2+tz^3=1\}$ differential manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

For which $t$ is followins set a differential manifold
$$
M_t=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x^2-y^2+tz^3=1\}
$$
I tried to analyze possible determinants of $2\times2$ matrixes from $ \begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y & 2z \\2x & -2y & 3tz^2 \end{bmatrix}$ but couldn't obtain acceptable result.

Comment: The right upper entry of the Jacobian should be $2z$.

Comment: It's ok now. Now I think my method weren't correct. Even if I find all $(x,y,z)$ where relevant determinants are 0, it wouldn't be enough to know exactly what happens with "manifoldity" in these points. Or maybe it would be if that points were excluded from $M_t$

Comment: I do not have an answer now, but I draw both surfaces for different values of $t$. They do not intersect for small positive values of $t$ whereas they do for large values. The later seems to be a smooth curve.

Comment: Did you draw this by yourself or with help of some software?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk I used Scientific work place.